# Here Weather API: Is there an Icon List?

Tags: here-api

I'm working on a weather station project and is using Here Weather API for current observation and forecast.

The problem that have occurred for me, is that I'm using a another set of weather icons than Here is providing and I can't translate it directly to the set I'm using. There is no weather icon list in the documentation that can explain what weather icon 25 is ([looks like this](https://weather.cit.api.here.com/static/weather/icon/25.png)).

Could someone provide a list of all the iconLinks and their iconNames? 
Something like this as it looks like in the response:

```
           "iconName": "mostly_cloudy",
           "iconLink": "https://weather.api.here.com/static/weather/icon/17.png",
```

Best of all would be if Here themselves could provide such information in their documentation (if I haven't missed that page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're aware of the list of all iconNames at https://developer.here.com/documentation/destination-weather/dev_guide/topics/resource-type-weather-items.html

This doesn't provide the mapping between the icon names and Here's own icons, but as you already have your own set of icons, you only need to map the given icon names on your own set.

With 150 entries it's a much longer list than Here's 32 icons, but many iconNames are repeated for early and late, and under iconLink they state "Note that an individual icon may be used for more than one of the iconName values given above".

And yeah, no idea what that icon 25 is supposed to represent. Maybe ice_fog?

Comment: Thank you! Didn't find that one due to I didn't dig deep enough into the API. I started to look at the API and didn't really find anything and gave up.